# CMake issues with target_include directories

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm working on a new project, and trying to set up cmake from the ground up for the first time. I have two libraries that get built as targets in my project; `libnet` and `liberror`. I am linking `libnet` with `liberror` when I build the `libnet` target, and want to be able to `#include` header files that exist within `liberror`. I have the following added to the `CMakeLists.txt` for `liberror`:

```
target_include_directories(liberror SYSTEM PUBLIC core/error)
```

Now, I have the following added to the `CMakeLists.txt` for `libnet`:

```
target_link_libraries(libnet
                  PUBLIC
                  liberror)
```

So, `liberror` provides a header called ExceptionBuilder.hpp. When I try to do the following from `libnet`:

```
#include <core/error/ExceptionBuilder.hpp>
```

I get this error:

```
fatal error: core/error/ExceptionBuilder.hpp: No such file or directory
3 | #include <core/error/ExceptionBuilder.hpp>
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

I am quite new to cmake, so probably just setting something up incorrectly here, but any ideas? Here is the project structure:

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y8SMs.png)

Here is the verbose build output:

```
nmcurtis@DESKTOP-JC26375:~/distro/build$ make
-- Boost version: 1.58.0
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/nmcurtis/distro/build
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target distro_core_error_objects
[ 11%] Built target distro_core_error_objects
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target distro_core_utility_objects
[ 16%] Built target distro_core_utility_objects
[ 22%] Linking CXX shared library libdistro_core_utility.so
/usr/local/gcc-11.3.0/bin/g++-11.3 -fPIC -fPIC -Wno-terminate -shared -Wl,-soname,libdistro_core_utility.so -o libdistro_core_utility.so CMakeFiles/distro_core_utility_objects.dir/Concepts.cpp.o 
[ 22%] Built target distro_core_utility
[ 27%] Linking CXX shared library libdistro_core_error.so
/usr/local/gcc-11.3.0/bin/g++-11.3 -fPIC -fPIC -Wno-terminate -shared -Wl,-soname,libdistro_core_error.so -o libdistro_core_error.so CMakeFiles/distro_core_error_objects.dir/Exception.cpp.o CMakeFiles/distro_core_error_objects.dir/ExceptionBuilder.cpp.o  -Wl,-rpath,/home/nmcurtis/distro/build/core/utility: ../utility/libdistro_core_utility.so 
[ 27%] Built target distro_core_error
[ 33%] Linking CXX static library libdistro_core_utility_static.a
/usr/bin/ar qc libdistro_core_utility_static.a CMakeFiles/distro_core_utility_objects.dir/Concepts.cpp.o
/usr/bin/ranlib libdistro_core_utility_static.a
[ 33%] Built target distro_core_utility_static
[ 38%] Linking CXX static library libdistro_core_error_static.a
/usr/bin/ar qc libdistro_core_error_static.a CMakeFiles/distro_core_error_objects.dir/Exception.cpp.o CMakeFiles/distro_core_error_objects.dir/ExceptionBuilder.cpp.o
/usr/bin/ranlib libdistro_core_error_static.a
[ 38%] Built target distro_core_error_static
Consolidate compiler generated dependencies of target distro_core_net_objects
[ 44%] Building CXX object core/net/CMakeFiles/distro_core_net_objects.dir/Address.cpp.o
/home/nmcurtis/distro/core/net/Address.cpp:4:10: fatal error: core/error/ExceptionBuilder.hpp: No such file or directory
    4 | #include <core/error/ExceptionBuilder.hpp>
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
core/net/CMakeFiles/distro_core_net_objects.dir/build.make:120: recipe for target 'core/net/CMakeFiles/distro_core_net_objects.dir/Address.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [core/net/CMakeFiles/distro_core_net_objects.dir/Address.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:262: recipe for target 'core/net/CMakeFiles/distro_core_net_objects.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [core/net/CMakeFiles/distro_core_net_objects.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:135: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
nmcurtis@DESKTOP-JC26375:~/distro/build$
```

Comment: Did you try double quotes `" "` instead of `< >` around the include? Like `#include "core/error/ExceptionBuilder.hpp"`

Comment: Yes, did not work.

Comment: Ok, i see......

Comment: More than likely, it is an issue with my project structure and cmake, as this is my first attempt to set up cmake from the ground up for a project. I can share more info if it would help you help me ofc.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and provide verbose build output.  That'll show the exact include paths that are being passed during compilation.

Comment: *I have the following added to the CMakeLists.txt* - you have four them! Which one?

Comment: The build output doesn't show any arguments to Address.cpp.  Try `make VERBOSE=1`

Answer (score 0):

If you do `target_include_directories(liberror SYSTEM PUBLIC core/error)` you do not need core/error in `#include <core/error/ExceptionBuilder.hpp>`

Do this in `core/error/CMakeLists.txt`.

```cmake
target_include_directories(liberror SYSTEM PUBLIC .)
# or
# target_include_directories(liberror SYSTEM PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})
```

```
#include "ExceptionBuilder.hpp"
```

If you wish `#include "core/error/ExceptionBuilder.hpp"`  then
do this in `core/error/CMakeLists.txt`.

```cmake
target_include_directories(liberror SYSTEM PUBLIC ../..)
# or
# target_include_directories(liberror SYSTEM PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/../..)
```

Comment: Still not working with these updates. Is it possibly something with my project structure / the way I'm linking that is causing a problem?

Comment: Then `core/error` is an invalid relative path. Which one of CMakeLists.txt has this directive? Try `.` or `error`instead of `core/error`

Comment: If you look at the project structure, it is the CMakeLists.txt in `core/error` that has this directive.

Comment: It should be `target_include_directories(liberror SYSTEM PUBLIC .)` and 
`#include "ExceptionBuilder.hpp"`

Comment: Alternatively it can be `target_include_directories(liberror SYSTEM PUBLIC ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` - the same effect as `target_include_directories(liberror SYSTEM PUBLIC .)` in `core/error/CMakeLists.txt`.